# Cannot enter edit mode or change to orthographic view?

Tags: 3d-view, documentation

I'm a beginner to all this video creation thing and started reading the "Introduction" and "Starting" of the Doc. 2.6 Manual. At the end of "Starting" there is "Your First Animation" where I tried "[1/2: A static Gingerbread Man](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Your_First_Animation/1.A_static_Gingerbread_Man)". There I had the following problems:

1. After moving the camera and lamp to the 10th layer the cube was *not* selected anymore. I selected it by *Select* -> *Select All by Layer*. Is this correct?
2. After using <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> I hit <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> but the front view still remained and did *not* change to the orthogonal view. By the way, why should I use <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> during this example?
3. By pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> I could *not* enter into Edit mode.

Could above problems result from my German keyboard and using Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, I don't think so. What matters is that the cube is *Active* (usually the last selected, with a yellow outline).

   In Blender there are [three selection states](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting#Selections_and_the_Active_Object):

   - Unselected
   - Selected
   - Active

   There can only be one active object at a time. The active object defines which object will go into edit mode when you press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>, which object's options are shown in the properties panel, etc.

   Selecting an object with <kbd>A</kbd>, *select by layer*, etc. will not change the active object.

   To make the cube active, click on it with <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>.
2. That's odd.. Are you sure the mouse cursor was over the 3D view?
3. I suspect this is because your active object was either the camera or the lamp, not the cube.

   You can tell which layer the active object is on by looking at the layers in *3D view > Header*. The orange dot represents the active object:

   [image]